# c++ HANDLE parameter turned into boolean false despite non zero value

Tags: c++, parameters

Good day.

I'm scratching my head over a problem I'm having in visual studio express 2012

I have the following code:

```
HANDLE hProc = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ; <= declared globally in cpp file

//my routine
//get myprocessid
//...
hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, myprocessid);
```

And the value of hProc is non zero.

Then in a different routine:

```
FARPROC varprocaddress = GetRemoteProcAddress (hProc, hModule, MethodName, 0, FALSE);
```

Problem is, when I debug the GetRemoteProcAddress routine,
the hProc value (in the hProcess variable) is FALSE, despite the fact I can clearly see it is passed as non false thanks to a variable watch, and so the routine obviously fails.

The getremoteprocaddress method is declared as this:

```
FARPROC WINAPI GetRemoteProcAddress (HANDLE hProcess, HMODULE hModule, LPCSTR lpProcName, UINT Ordinal, BOOL UseOrdinal)
```

Can anybody help?
It's obvious that the hProc parameter is not zero, then why it is converted to zero upon function call?

The issue seems related to the handle value outside of the function call... but how can I tell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GetRemoteProcAddress from codeproject.com? What's giving you the impression of a FALSE value for the HANDLE variable?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That's the code I'm using. The false value is clearly identified with a watch and a breakpoint, just inside the function. Besides, the function fails the GetModuleInformation call miserably :(

Comment: Are you sure you are using same variable? Two same declarations in different cpp files are different declarations.

Comment: Post the code in between `hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, myprocessid);` and `FARPROC varprocaddress = GetRemoteProcAddress (hProc, hModule, MethodName, 0, FALSE);`, or if you're convinced that the value is changing (to a different type - which doesn't really make sense), then set a [data breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to catch when / where it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the reason for the handle mangling was that the getremoteprocaddress call was inside a

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc
```

in an user driven event (click on a menu).

Could not really figure out -why- this happened, but after I moved the `FARPROC varprocaddress = GetRemoteProcAddress ...`
call inside a new function, and placed the new function call in the menu click event, the global handle valued passed fine into the getremoteprocaddress!